# Different scheduled tasks' Behaviour

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I have a piece of code, which schedules task to repeat every 10 (3,5,20,60, doesn't matter) seconds with this classes: 
`AlarmManager + BroadcastReceiver + IntentService`

On SDK Emulator (4.2.2) it works fine

```
07-12 09:02:32.257: INFO/Alarm Receiver(1827): Entered
07-12 09:02:42.256: INFO/Alarm Receiver(1827): Entered
07-12 09:02:52.275: INFO/Alarm Receiver(1827): Entered
```

But on my phone `Xiaomi MI-2S (4.1.1)` it fires only every 5 minutes

```
07-12 16:06:07.044: INFO/Alarm Receiver(5632): Entered
07-12 16:11:06.874: INFO/Alarm Receiver(5632): Entered
07-12 16:16:06.864: INFO/Alarm Receiver(5632): Entered
```

What's the problem?

upd. here's the code

**Activity**

```
public void startSchedule
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pIntent);
}

public void endSchedule
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.cancel(pIntent);
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{

    Log.i("Alarm Receiver", "Entered");
    context.startService(inService);
}
```

**IntentService** empty for now

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) 
{
    // Do some task
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code :)

Comment: It's not the code problem! Tried on my tablet, running ICS 4.0.3, got expected result: it logs every 10 seconds. So I think it's my phone's problem. I really don't know where to post about this problem))

Comment: Moreover, tried to set AlarmManager to fire every 6 minutes! On the problem phone it fires every 10 minutes in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of Xiaomi's v5 firmware!
I've found a workaround to make my app work, but I think there will be problems with waking up. I use

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

instead of

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```